# Raise CanExecuteChanged when the model changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, delegatecommand

In my `ViewModel` I have an `ObservableCollection` of `Person` objects (that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and a `SelectedPerson` property. These are bound to a ListBox in my view.

There is also the following Prism DelegateCommand in my ViewModel:

```
Private DelegateCommand _myCommand = New DelegateCommand(CanExecute)
Public DelegateCommand MyCommand {get {return _myCommand;}}

Private Bool CanExecute()
{
    Return (SelectedPerson.Age > 40);
}
```

What is the most elegant way of calling MyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged whenever the `SelectedPerson` changes **and** whenever the `SelectedPerson`'s age changes?

Adding and removing property changed handlers in the `SelectedPerson`'s setter seems a bit messy to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding and removing property changed handlers in the SelectedPerson's setter seems a bit messy to me.

That's how I do it, and I'm not sure what a cleaner alternative would be.  If the command state depends on a sub-property, you need to observe the changes *somehow*.  Be careful about unsubscribing, though, or you risk a memory leak if your `Person` outlives your view model.  `PropertyChangedEventManager` and weak event handlers can help if you can't guarantee that you unsubscribe.

To keep things clean, I usually just have one handler that listens for any sub-property changes, which calls a `RequeryCommands` method (also called directly by view model methods), which in turn invokes `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` for *all* the commands in my view.